# Sending data over multiple available networks

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am developing an application to transfer large amount of data(Probably in GB's) to server.But if i send it over a single network it takes a long time to get transferred. I am having multiple network connections from different ISP's, to which my PC can connect through Ethernet Port, WiFi and USB Dongle. Is there any way through which I can distribute my data over these three available channels(like first data packet go over ethernet,2nd data packet over WiFi, 3rd over USB Dongle, 4th again over ethernet and so on) for faster transmission.Is, this possible? If yes, How can i access these three networks simultaneously for sending data

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any API around for this already. May be that you have to open 3 connections for the 3 networks and while sending the data use an algorithm ( threads per connection etc or round robin scheduling.,) to spread the data across the three networks, have your own header where it has packet number, packet length and so forth. when you receive back at the server, use a buffer to collect and re-arrange them. once you find that all the data is rx'ed. shutdown!

Comment: @RC HI. How can i open connections to different network can u provide any reference .Thanks

Comment: Get the ip-address of the three network interfaces and use socket bind interface. <SOCK1:IP1:PORT1>, <SOCK2:IP2:PORT2>, <SOCK3:IP3:PORT3> or same port if you like.

Comment: @ RC sir u mean i need to create a  socket for each available IP(network) and then bind it to same port and with each ip.

Comment: @RC can this type of thing also work for Android or Ios Device

Comment: yes. hopefully it should work. This is the basic approach one can start off with. May be you can investigate if there are any apis around this to make your work easy.

Comment: Which protocol do you use for transfer ? Do you write only the Sender or the receiver too ?

Comment: Maybe this solution will help to share usb dongle http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26515

Answer (score 0):

This is policy based routing, generally it isn't an easy thing to do.

The routing of network packets is usually only dependent on the destination that the packets are being sent to. So if a device has multiple interfaces all the packets for one remote will normally go out the same interface.

If the remote has multiple IP addresses you can easily route the different destinations out through different interfaces. BUT for "different ISPs" the local address will normally need to match the interface that you're sending the packets out through so that the replies come back in the same interface. (Most firewalls get a little worried, ie start blocking, if this is wrong)

With a "policy" in place you can put in rules that say that "if the local address is X send the packets out of interface B". At which point you can start dividing the traffic using the bind source address that "RC Brand" suggested.

The most generic way to join these links together completely is to setup a VPN tunnel to a remote host and arrange for the packets that make up the tunnel to be shared to the different links. (eg round robin policy based routing)

This is called a bonded connection, people sell these (bonded ADSL).

For your **specific** problem -- sending a big file.

1. A disk/flash drive in the mail has a very large bandwidth (ping time
   sucks though). You can get better ping time with a bike.
2. You could use an archiver program (7-zip) to split the file into multiple parts, send each one from a different machine out a different ISP. Stick them back together at the other end.
3. Bonded connections, either homemade or commercial.